# How to i play sound using the sound library in processing?

Tags: processing

I'm trying to play some music in my project. I followed a tutorial in which the following code worked but when I try it I get an error message which says:
"Jan 06, 2020 9:38:55 PM com.jsyn.devices.javasound.JavaSoundAudioDevice 
INFO: JSyn: default output latency set to 80 msec for Windows 10"

```
import processing.sound.*;
SoundFile song;

void setup() {

   size(1300, 500);
   background(0);
   song = new SoundFile(this, "song.mp3");
   song.play();
}
```

[tutorial i followed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJJCci3kXe0)

[library I'm trying to use](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/sound/index.html)

Comment: Update: okay I've found that it does play, however, there's a long delay at the start and it isn't instant like in the tutorial. Also, the pitch is lower

Comment: You can load the sound before you actually need it, just like in most professional games. Well, it won't change anything in this precise case since you pretty much only load a sound, but if you had a "beep" everytime your character does something, you would want to load it only once and use the same sound for every beep.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: In a way, you just did. The `song = new SoundFile(this, "song.mp3");` line load the sound into memory. It's in the `setup` method because this method runs automatically, once. It's a great place to load stuff and prepare whatever you want to be ready for later. Because `song` is a global variable, it'll stay in memory as long as the program runs, and you can call it from any method. So you only have to load it once, in the `setup`, and later you can play it as many times as you want, without having to load it again.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the song to play since the console message is simply an `INFO` log message (not as high priority as `WARNING` or `ERROR`)

Also does having a `draw()` loop make a difference ?

```
import processing.sound.*;
SoundFile song;

void setup() {

   size(1300, 500);
   song = new SoundFile(this, "song.mp3");
   song.play();
}
void draw(){
   background(0);
   text("song.isPlaying() = " + song.isPlaying(), 10, 15);
}
```

It might be that the mp3 has encoding properties (bit depth, sample rate, etc.) that the Processing Sound library can't decode. 
It's worth trying to export your mp3 file to a WAV file (unsigned 16bit 44100 Hz).
(You can do this with an opensource tool such as [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/))